# Router not found in Netgear Nighthawk iOS app?

Tags: ios, wifi, vpn, router, icloud-plus

I’m connected to the router via WiFi, I’ve reinstalled the app and given it all permissions, and I’m not using a VPN.

Comment: Have you given it permission to access the local network / local devices?

Comment: @anonymous yes I did. Clarified, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Temporarily turn off Private Relay in iOS’s iCloud settings to connect to the router.